# submit button is no more disabled in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm working with angular5  i have a file .html that containes a form with 2 input of type dates and an input type text .

I'm implementing a  condition : if input dateOne is greater than dateTwo an error appears to the user else he can submit the form .

Everything works well , the button submit is disabled but when  i choose the dateOne  greater than dateTwo the error message appears and the button is no more disabled  .

The button is no more disabled if first input and both dates are not empty . it doesnt considere the condition i'have made in the function validation() .

This is File .html

```
 <div class="modal-content">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addProjecToClients()" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Affectation du projet aux clients</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="largeModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">


    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Choisir un client : </label>


      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
                     [items]="_listClients"
                      bindLabel ="nom"
                      bindValue ="id"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId"
                    formControlName="selectedPersonId"
        >
        </ng-select>

      </div>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Information liées au contrat : </label>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >Date One :  </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm"
               placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateOne" formControlName="dateOne">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Date Two : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date"  [(ngModel)]="dateTwo" formControlName="dateTwo"  class="form-control form-control-sm"
               placeholder=".form-control-sm">

        <span style="color:red" *ngIf="validation()">Date fin doit etre plus grand que date debut .</span>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="largeModal.hide()">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

This is File .ts

```
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  dateOne:new Date() ;
  dateTwo:new Date(); 

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.doSearch();
    this.dateOne= null;
    this.dateTwo= null;

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateOne: ['', Validators.required],
      dateTwo: ['', Validators.required],
      selectedPersonId: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  validation(){
    if(this.dateOne && this.dateTwo){
      if(this.dateOne.getTime() < this.dateTwo.getTime()){
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }

  }

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You have unclosed `div`(last one?) inside `form` tag. See formated code block.

Comment: @Pengyy  : No there is no problem with div , it was my mistake when i was trying to past the code and editing it , you can see it now :) .

Comment: Submit button only check if form is valid which is true when you enter both dates. You have to create custom validator to check if date you enter are valid means dateOne is than dateTwo. Add custom validation in formbuilder or do this [disabled]=“form.invalid || !validation()” . Sorry for typo typing from phone.

Comment: also you are using both Template driven form and Reactive form here. For better understanding of forms, i'll suggest you to read this blog post https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/